# This application has no explicit mapping for /error, while calling from one service to another using feign

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

{
"timestamp": "2022-07-03T09:38:12.692+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"trace": "feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404] during [GET] to [http://stock-Api/get/MRF] [Cal#invokegetprice(String)]: [{"timestamp":"2022-07-03T09:38:12.685+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/get/MRF"}]\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:219)\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194)\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185)\r\n\tat feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92)\r\n\tat feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)\r\n\tat feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy108.invokegetprice(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.stock.demo.Controller.CalController.cal(CalController.java:22)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\n",
"message": "[404] during [GET] to [http://stock-Api/get/MRF] [Cal#invokegetprice(String)]: [{"timestamp":"2022-07-03T09:38:12.685+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/get/MRF"}]",
"path": "/gettotal/MRF/2"
}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Need to see minimal project structure as well , also, ensure you have `@ComponentScan` mentioned along with `@SpringBootApplication` , your controller class where your end points are defined might not be getting scanned ! `"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/get/MRF  `